# Can I use TFS 2013 for Continuous Integration for non microsoft stack OSes? i.e. android, mac, iOS, etc

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation

For Continuous Integration, is TFS a Microsoft technology stack only solution? If I have projects that require building apps for every major desktop and mobile OS platform, is TFS an appropriate Continuous Integration solution or do I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your TFS build to compile/build your app (for example I have a build that is compiling Oracle forms on Linux). You can use this link as a start: [Customize your build process template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx)

Comment: Also check out: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2011f516-15a7-4f9a-8b86-1e0894a75739